# Can a Java application create a report in LibreOffice?

Tags: java, reporting, report, libreoffice

I was looking into LibreOffice Base and I was impressed that they have reporting templates.  So now I'm wondering, can my Java application call LibreOffice and produce reports?  And can it pass in the parameters that the report would need?

Comment: I'm getting some good input, but what I'd really like is my user to be able to put in input parameters, so the report could run based on the specifics that they want.

Answer (score 3):

Libre Office saves documents in the [OpenDocument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) format, which uses XML.

I'm assuming that Libre Office saves templates in a similar XML format.

Your Java application can read a template file, process it, and output an XML report in the OpenDocument format, which Libre Office can read, without your Java application having to open Libre Office.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Apache POI Library](http://poi.apache.org/) for this. It's pretty much the standard in Java for any office document. I've used a lot of libraries over the years, most have one advantage or the other but you're pretty safe with Apache POI. OpenDocument format is just XML same as MS Word the `DOCX` format. As a matter of fact, rename any `docx` document to `.zip` and you'll be able to see the `xml`.

Answer (score 2):

If this still is interesting this project might help: http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/